# process not defined when using npm react package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am including npm react package in a script in the following way:

`var react = require('react');`

I am using node however when i do this and run my local node server i get the following error in the browser:

```
checkPropTypes.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object.6../lib/ReactPropTypesSecret (checkPropTypes.js:12)
at s (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.8../checkPropTypes (factoryWithTypeCheckers.js:17)
at s (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.7../factoryWithTypeCheckers (factory.js:16)
at s (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.24../ReactElement (ReactPropTypes.js:16)
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error. I have tried to set NODE_ENV environmental variable using:

`export NODE_ENV='development'`

If anyone could shed any light on why i am getting this error that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: For the record, the error is thrown [here](https://github.com/reactjs/prop-types/blob/master/checkPropTypes.js#L12), in the `checkPropTypes.js` file of React's `prop-types` module